# How to add new rows automatically in ACF by category name

Tags: php

I have a problem to add new rows of series and new rows of epizodes of serials automatically in Wordpress admin  with ACF plugin. I have repeater field o1, text field s for series, nested repeater o2 and link field e for epizodes. For example serial Godfather: I will add a new row of serie and new row of episode of the serial. I need that new row of serie and the new row of episode to be added automatically to all the series and episodes I've created before. I use category name to distinguish the serials. I can't write the code that will solve it. Can you help me write code that will be work? Here is the code so far:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('o1') ):
   while( have_rows('o1') ): the_row(); 
   ?>
<button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn"><?php the_sub_field('s'); ?></button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <?php
    if( have_rows('o2') ):
    while ( have_rows('o2') ) : the_row();
$link = get_sub_field('e');
    if( $link ): 
    $link_url = $link['url'];
    $link_title = $link['title'];
    $link_target = $link['target']? $link['target'] : '_self';
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>" target="<?php
    echo esc_attr( $link_target ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_title ); ?><br></a>
<?php endif;         
 endwhile;
else :
endif; ?>  </div>  <?php
endwhile; 
endif;  
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated